# Context free grammar for the same amount of a’s and b’s, with the b’s in the middle

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need to convert the following language to a CFG
$$
L = \{\ a^n b^{n+k} a^k \in \{a,b\}^* \ |\ n \ge 0\ ,\ k\ge 0 \}
\ .
$$
So far I have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    S &\Rightarrow SASBSA \ ,\\
    A &\Rightarrow a\ ,\\
    B &\Rightarrow bb|b\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
But I don't think this is correct. It's not quite a palindrome as $n$ and $k$ can be odd. I'm struggling with the $n+k$ part.

Comment: Please show your attempt and add context.

Comment: Hint: It might help to view the general element as $a^n b^n \cdot b^k a^k$ and then split the generation of this element into the two parts.

Comment: ah ok so the same amount of a's and b's, then the same amount of b's and a's, excuse the formatting but like:
S->TQ, T->SASBS, Q->SBSAS, A->a, B->b

Comment: How do you get rid of the occurrence of either $S$, or $T$ (using the above rules)? Why not $S\to TU$, and $T$ can generate only $aTb$ or $T'$, and $U$ only $bUa$ or $U'$, and arrange that $T',U'$ are then replaced only by the empty string.

Comment: not sure i understand that, my knowledge is very limited. What does $T'$ and $U'$ mean?

Comment: I think what @dan_fulea is suggesting is something like $T\Rightarrow aTb | T'$, $T'\Rightarrow \varepsilon$, and similarly for $U$ and $U'$.  (Though it's pretty much equivalent to use just $T \Rightarrow aTb | \varepsilon$.)

Comment: thanks, so S ⇒ TU, T ⇒ aTb | T', U ⇒ bUa | U', T'⇒ , U'⇒  ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ′ syntax (the apostrophe bit), could ′ be replaced by another variable name, X, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can have $a^nb^n$ and $b^na^n$ we can generate our strings by multiplying a prefix $P$ by a suffix $Q$. Let $S$ be our start symbol.
$$S\to\epsilon$$
$$S\to P$$
$$S\to Q$$
$$S\to PQ$$
$$P\to aPb$$
$$Q\to bQa$$
$$P\to ab$$
$$Q\to ba$$